# Simple Jetty app built with Maven according to instructions returns 404

Tags: maven, jetty

I am attempting to follow the instructions at:

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/maven-and-jetty.html

I have created three files:

**/Users/dlynch/eclipse-workspace2/swbpp/src/main/java/org/firezeal/SwbppServlet.java**

```
package org.firezeal;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SwbppServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello Servlet</h1>");
        response.getWriter().println("session=" + request.getSession(true).getId());
    }
}
```

**/Users/dlynch/eclipse-workspace2/swbpp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
   metadata-complete="false"
   version="3.1">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>swbpp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.firezeal.SwbppServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>swbpp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/swbpp/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**/Users/dlynch/eclipse-workspace2/swbpp/pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.firezeal</groupId>
  <artifactId>SwbppServlet</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Jetty HelloWorld WebApp</name>

  <properties>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
      <jettyVersion>9.4.9.v20180320</jettyVersion>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jettyVersion}</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Maven compiles the project fine. I then run jetty:

```
MacBook-Pro-504% java -jar "${JETTY_HOME}"/start.jar
2018-04-06 09:46:09.670:INFO::main: Logging initialized @596ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2018-04-06 09:46:09.916:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.9.v20180320; built: 2018-03-20T05:21:10-07:00; git: 1f8159b1e4a42d3f79997021ea1609f2fbac6de5; jvm 9.0.4+11
2018-04-06 09:46:09.928:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///Users/dlynch/Services/Jetty-Base/swbpp/webapps/] at interval 1
2018-04-06 09:46:10.015:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /SwbppServlet-1, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2018-04-06 09:46:10.021:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2018-04-06 09:46:10.021:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2018-04-06 09:46:10.022:INFO:oejs.session:main: Scavenging every 660000ms
2018-04-06 09:46:10.048:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1ffaf86{/SwbppServlet-1,file:///private/var/folders/t3/zbrns2cx3396mjbqhnzwfhz00000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-SwbppServlet-1.war-_SwbppServlet-1-any-2425585091937596948.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/SwbppServlet-1.war}
2018-04-06 09:46:10.114:WARN::main: async-rest webapp is deployed. DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION!
2018-04-06 09:46:10.115:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2018-04-06 09:46:10.118:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4f49f6af{/,[file:///private/var/folders/t3/zbrns2cx3396mjbqhnzwfhz00000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-ROOT.war-_-any-10196676678941755136.dir/webapp/, jar:file:///private/var/folders/t3/zbrns2cx3396mjbqhnzwfhz00000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-ROOT.war-_-any-10196676678941755136.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/example-async-rest-jar-9.4.9.v20180320.jar!/META-INF/resources],AVAILABLE}{/ROOT.war}
2018-04-06 09:46:10.155:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@72ef8d15{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2018-04-06 09:46:10.155:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1082ms
```

When attempting to access http://127.0.0.1:8080/swbpp the server returns a 404.

However, I can access / because I copied over the ROOT.war, which shows an example eBay application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a previous reply I learned that the context that was being set was incorrect, rather than changing the name of the file, I learned that you could generate a different XML file from here:

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/configuring-specific-webapp-deployment.html

So I dropped a SwbppServlet-1.xml file into ${JETTY_BASE}/webapps which reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/swbpp</Set>
  <Set name="war">/Users/dlynch/Services/Jetty-Base/swbpp/webapps/SwbppServlet-1.war</Set>
  <Set name="extractWAR">false</Set>
</Configure>
```

At that point I was getting a directory listing instead of my code being ran. After reviewing:

[Jetty Servlet does not run -- getting directory listing instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328891/jetty-servlet-does-not-run-getting-directory-listing-instead)

I changed my WEB_INF/web.xml file to say:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
   metadata-complete="false"
   version="3.1">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>swbpp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.firezeal.SwbppServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>swbpp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I presume that since the context was already set, the url pattern should be /, and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The line ...

> 2018-04-06 09:46:10.118:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4f49f6af{/,[file:///private/var/folders/t3/zbrns2cx3396mjbqhnzwfhz00000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-ROOT.war-*-any-10196676678941755136.dir/webapp/, jar:file:///private/var/folders/t3/zbrns2cx3396mjbqhnzwfhz00000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-ROOT.war-*-any-10196676678941755136.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/example-async-rest-jar-9.4.9.v20180320.jar!/META-INF/resources],AVAILABLE}{/ROOT.war}

Says the webapp was deployed at `contextRoot` of `/`

So try `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` for the "base resource" (aka home/root location) of your context (which might produce a 404 if you have no `src/main/webapp/index.html` or a directory listing if your environment is configured as such)

Your chosen `url-pattern` of `/swbpp/*` means that you can use the following path examples to test that servlet.

```
Request URI                       | status | request.getPathInfo()
--------------------------------- | ------ | ---------------------
http://127.0.0.1:8080/swbpp       | 404    | (n/a - see below)
http://127.0.0.1:8080/swbpp/      | 200    | "/"
http://127.0.0.1:8080/swbpp/foo   | 200    | "/foo"
http://127.0.0.1:8080/swbpp/a/b/c | 200    | "/a/b/c"
```

That is because `/swbpp` is not part of that url-pattern.

If you had a file called, say `src/main/webapp/swbpp` then the contents of that file would be served when requesting `/swbpp`